# How to manage dependencies between different applications services while deploying on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, package, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-operator

There are web applications - **WebAppA** and **WebAppB**. Each web application depend on a Postgres database. We want to ship these applications to a customer who will deploy the applications on its own k8s cluster.

We want to create three packages - "**WebappA**", "**WebAppB**" and "**Datastore**". The webapp itself made of multiple services, not mentioning for the sake of simplicity.

We want to provide **apt-get/brew/yum** kind of experience, so that customer can deploy one or both the applications like al-carte. Most importantly while deploying, it should identify if the common package "**DataStore**" is running and not spin off yet another Postgres instance.

Is there any to package applications as packages for Kubernetes which can make installation easy with dependency handling?

Comment: Please refer to these documents. [Doc1](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/automating-deployment-pod-dependencies-in-kubernetes/) and [doc2](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/kubernetes-demystified-solving-service-dependencies_594110).

Answer (score 0):

Of course! One way to start would be using Helm charts. You can read more about them [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/).

Helm defines dependency relationships declaratively using charts, allows you to manipulate/maintain dependencies simply by managing some YAML manifests. It also allows you to have personalised repositories where you can put your images to be fetched from. It's really nice.